# D3 parcoords axis scale not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm using the [d3 parcoords](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/) library. When I modify data plotted in a parallel coordinates chart, and reload the chart, the scale of the axis isn't refreshed.

I tried calling `.autoscale()`, but if I call it before `.render()`, it has no effect, and if I call it after `.render()`, then no polylines are drawn anymore.

```
    $("#example").html(""); //to make sure "ghost" axes are removed

            parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#example")
                .data(parsedData)
                .createAxes()
                .brushMode("1D-axes")
                .reorderable()//;
                .detectDimensions()
                .dimensions(dimensionObj)
                .autoscale() //no visible effect if placed here
                .render()
                .updateAxes();
```

Not sure if this is related (although the issue started at the same time), I started specifying an order for the dimensions. To do this, instead of using an array containing the axes (`dimensionArray`), I use a JS object `dimensionObj` containing numbered "index" keys, as follows:

```
//dimensionArray = ["axis1", "axis2", "axis3", "axis4"]; //orderless array

//Default axes to display with predefined ordering
dimensionObj = {
  "axis1": {index:0},
  "axis2": {index:1},
  "axis3": {index:2},
  "axis4": {index:3}
  }
```

For illustration purposes, the following screenshots show how on the top image, the scales are properly set, but on the second (updated) chart, some new polylines are going to 0 on the 1st and 3rd axis, but the scale isn't updated so lines go out of range.

Is there a simple way to refresh the axis scales when reloading a chart? Is it possible that using the JS object in `.dimensions()` is creating some conflicts with the underlying scale function?

[image: 1st chart with default data]

[image: 2nd updated chart with updated data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was causing this behaviour: an `if` statement in d3.parcoords.js `pc.autoscale` function which was only resetting scales if the `yscale` was not previously defined. Essentially I edited the `if` statement from original:

```
  d3.keys(__.dimensions).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!__.dimensions[k].yscale){
      __.dimensions[k].yscale = defaultScales[__.dimensions[k].type](k);
    }
  });
```

to this (of course the `if` statement could be dropped altogether, I simply kept it in this form in case I need to revert to original version later for any reason):

```
  d3.keys(__.dimensions).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!__.dimensions[k].yscale || __.dimensions[k].yscale){
      __.dimensions[k].yscale = defaultScales[__.dimensions[k].type](k);
    }
  });
```